# Headphones not working on Alienware15(2015)

Tags: headphones

Headphones are not working on Alienware 15 (2016) running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS(64 bit) and windows 10 in a dual boot configuration.The audio PulseAudio Volume Control detects the headphones when plugged in but continues to play audio through the speakers.Headphones work fine on windows though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you set the headphones to be on?

1. Open sound settings. (click that speaker icon on the top, and click "Sound Settings"
2. Click "Output"
3. Select your headphones.

If the headphones it's not in the list, make sure you've proper drivers installed.

Comment: The headphones are detected by the sound mixer.But audio continues to play through the inbuilt speakers.

Comment: Have you selected them?